# sorting the xmlElement by the child value with sort attribute value provided by User

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```html
<root>
 <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496761802">06/06/2017  03:10:02 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> abc</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  None</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">  1 </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> efg</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496743990">06/06/2017  10:13:10 AM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>3
   <Cell columnid="3"> o</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> None</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5"> 1 </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6">  N/A </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> ice age</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496227357">31/05/2017  10:42:37 AM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3">  Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5"> 513</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7">Access is denied.. </Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568786">23/05/2017  07:46:26 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">2484</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6">SR</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7">hello</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568789">23/05/2017  07:46:29 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2">Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Application Hang </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">1002</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> here is a error</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568740">23/05/2017  07:45:40 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Application Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> Application Crashing Events</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">1000</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> error number 3</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
</root>
```

If i want to sort the sectionItem element base on Cell element value of the Cell attribute columnID giving by user, how can i approach this? Thank you in advance.

e.g. if user give colunid "1", then we want to sort the sectionItem base on the value of Cell with columnid="1".
if user give colunid "3", then we want to sort the sectionItem base on the value of Cell with columnid="3".

Hope that will make the question easier to understand as i am having difficulty putting the question together.

If i am sorting  with columnid="3"

i should get the the below output:

```html
<root>
 <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496761802">06/06/2017  03:10:02 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> abc</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  None</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">  1 </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> efg</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568740">23/05/2017  07:45:40 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Application Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> Application Crashing Events</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">1000</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> error number 3</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
   <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568789">23/05/2017  07:46:29 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2">Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Application Hang </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">1002</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> here is a error</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496227357">31/05/2017  10:42:37 AM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3">  Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5"> 513</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7">Access is denied.. </Cell>
  </SectionItem>
  <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1495568786">23/05/2017  07:46:26 PM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="3"> Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4">  N/A</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5">2484</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6">SR</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7">hello</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
   <SectionItem>
   <Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496743990">06/06/2017  10:13:10 AM</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>3
   <Cell columnid="3"> o</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="4"> None</Cell>
   <Cell columnid="5"> 1 </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="6">  N/A </Cell>
   <Cell columnid="7"> ice age</Cell>
  </SectionItem>
</root>
```

Comment: You might want to give https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview a read.  It sounds like you might use linq to grab all the SectionItem elements, then select the (sub)Cell element values based on the columnid attribute and call Sort() on the result.  It's not really clear what you expect from this sort; the SectionItem attributes?, the Cell values?  Anyway, it looks like something that could be done with a fairly straight forward linq query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to get the sectionItem element in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

You really have a datatable and should use mehtod DataTable.ReadXml(), but you didn't posted all the real xml data so I couldn't parse the xml with your input.  Instead I put parsed the xml input a data table using a custom xml linq parser.  It also didn't help that you added extra spaces in the innertex so I had to trim out the spaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Results", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 4", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 5", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));


         //<Cell columnid="1" InSeconds="1496227357">31/05/2017  10:42:37 AM</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="2"> Error</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="3">  Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="4">  N/A</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="5"> 513</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="6"> N/A</Cell>
         //<Cell columnid="7">Access is denied.. </Cell>

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement sectionItem in doc.Descendants("SectionItem"))
            {
                XElement[] cells = sectionItem.Elements("Cell").ToArray();
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                   DateTime.ParseExact( (string)cells[0],"dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                   ((string)cells[1]).Trim(),
                   ((string)cells[2]).Trim(),
                   ((string)cells[3]).Trim(),
                   (int)cells[4],
                   ((string)cells[5]).Trim(),
                   ((string)cells[6]).Trim(),

                });
            }

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).CopyToDataTable();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of what I was thinking about when I made my comment.  Note that the heart of this is the following linq statement:

```
var cells = xdoc.Element("root")
                .Elements("SectionItem")
                .Elements("Cell")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("columnid").Value == sortCol)
                .OrderBy(x => ParseCol(sortCol, x));
```

This starts at element "root", enumerates over all it's subelements "SectionItem" and over all their subelements "Cell" selecting the ones that match the sortCol, then sorts the enumeration (based on the types returned from a ParseCol function that provides appropriate type conversion for you XML string data.

I do like [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)'s DataTable approach, particularly if you are going to display this in some form of a gird/list.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ParseXml {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var xml = @"
<root>
<SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1496761802'>06/06/2017  03:10:02 PM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'> Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='3'> abc</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'>  None</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'>  1 </Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'> N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'> efg</Cell>
 </SectionItem>
 <SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1496743990'>06/06/2017  10:13:10 AM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'> Error</Cell>3
     <Cell columnid='3'> o</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'> None</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'> 1 </Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'>  N/A </Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'> ice age</Cell>
 </SectionItem>
 <SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1496227357'>31/05/2017  10:42:37 AM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'> Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='3'>  Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'>  N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'> 513</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'> N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'>Access is denied.. </Cell>
 </SectionItem>
 <SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1495568786'>23/05/2017  07:46:26 PM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'> Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='3'> Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'>  N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'>2484</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'>SR</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'>hello</Cell>
 </SectionItem>
 <SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1495568789'>23/05/2017  07:46:29 PM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'>Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='3'> Application Hang </Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'> N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'>1002</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'> N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'> here is a error</Cell>
 </SectionItem>
 <SectionItem>
     <Cell columnid='1' InSeconds='1495568740'>23/05/2017  07:45:40 PM</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='2'> Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='3'> Application Error</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='4'> Application Crashing Events</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='5'>1000</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='6'> N/A</Cell>
     <Cell columnid='7'> error number 3</Cell>
 </SectionItem>
</root>";

    var sortCol = "3";
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var cells = xdoc.Element("root")
                    .Elements("SectionItem")
                    .Elements("Cell")
                    .Where(x => x.Attribute("columnid").Value == sortCol)
                    .OrderBy(x => ParseCol(sortCol, x));

    var newDoc = new XDocument();
    var root = new XElement("root");
    newDoc.Add(root);
    foreach (var c in cells) {
        root.Add(c.Parent);
        }

    Console.WriteLine(newDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.None));
    }

    static object ParseCol(string col, XElement x) {
        switch (col) {
        case "1":
            return long.Parse(x.Attribute("InSeconds").Value);
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
            return x.Value.Trim();
        case "5":
            return long.Parse(x.Value);
        case "6":
        case "7":
            return x.Value.Trim();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Bad column id string");
        }
    }
}
```

}